# No user on ubuntu aws instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh

We recently cannot ssh inside to one of our instances. We assume it had to do with the key so we created a new key and attempt to replace the old one with it.

We created a new instance then mounted the old instance volume to the new one and ssh to the new instance.

When we tried to copy the .ssh folder from the new instance to the old, we noticed that the old instance does not have users in it (which explains why we can't ssh in the first place).

How can you add a user to a mounted volume?
we tried `sudo useradd -d /mnt/home/<name> -d <name>` but that did not work at all.

Comment: We followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMEY_S2XLGM)

Answer (score 1):

humm, the default ec2 user for ubuntu box should be `ubuntu`. If you did not find it, it may be that someone deleted it.

> How can you add a user to a mounted volume? we tried `sudo useradd -d
>   /mnt/home/<name> -d <name>` but that did not work at all.

well, I guess it did work but it created the user on the current instance, the system does not know that your mounted drive is a system drive for another instance.

What you can do:

- copy your current `/home/ubuntu` folder from the new instance to the old one (it should even copy your ssh key then). Pay attention to the permission and ownership of the folder
- go to `/mnt/etc` and hack the following files (you can even compare them with same files from your `/etc` directory, add the corresponding lines for the ubuntu user you are adding

  - mnt/etc/passwd
  - mnt/etc/group
  - mnt/etc/shadow
  - mnt/etc/gshadow

once all files are saved you can unmount the EBS drive and attach it to another instance as root drive, you should be able to login with `ubuntu` user (or any other user you have added following the steps)

Comment: What do you mean by compare the same files?
Should I only check that only concerns the 'ubuntu' user?

Comment: didn't work. I guess I'll have to copy the files onto a new instance.